# Problem with WordPress featured image thumbnail sizes and names in code

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails, wordpress-featured-image

[I messed up because I don't now much (or any) PHP.]

Recently I changed themes. Both themes are using identical thumbnail sizes for post links in various sections. My problem: *the thumbnails are **named differently** in both themes!*

The previous theme has this code to register thumbnails:

```
'thumb-small', 160, 160, true );
'thumb-standard', 320, 320, true );
'thumb-medium', 520, 245, true );
'thumb-large', 720, 340, true );
```

The new current theme uses this code and naming structure:

```
'kontrast-small', 160, 160, true );
'kontrast-standard', 320, 320, true );
'kontrast-medium', 520, 245, true );
'kontrast-large', 720, 340, true );
```

Since I didn't know any better I changed all instances of the new theme's calls for thumbnails, eg I replaced (in my child theme) the `<?php the_post_thumbnail('kontrast-medium'); ?>` with `<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumb-medium'); ?>`, the old name.

This means that all featured image thumbnails from the old theme are displayed in the correct size in the new one. Now, that I have published the first new post my theme (of course) doesn't find the matching thumbnail and displays an image that's wrong in dimensions. I assume this mess is related to some database entries, which refer to the theme's naming structure for thumbnails.

**How can I fix this? 
Any suggestion for some php function which could replace my messy code replacement?**

*Further explanation:* all my featured images have the post title as graphic text overlay on the image; any automatic WordPress cropping usually cuts off some of the text or makes it too small to read. So I created all sizes manually and uploaded them via FTP, replacing the automatically generated versions. *Hence I cannot use the normally suggested "Regenerate Thumbnails" plugin.* The blog is is over 6 years old and has nearly 250 posts - too much time and work to re-upload each thumbnail into the matching sub-directories.

The problem can be seen here https://dare2go.com/galleries/street-art/